# leer letras en específico de un TextArea

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola el lenguaje que utilizo es java en específico  estoy trabajando en un Jframe la acción se activa al presionar un botón.
El TextArea es mi contenedor el cual puedo poner infinidad de palabras, después viene una opcion en donde uno busca cuantas veces se repite cierta letra, luego preciona un boton el cual es que busca las letras y las cuenta para el final mostrarle los resultados en una opción de bajo de la letra a buscar.

Miren el problema es que tengo que leer letras en específico de un TextArea pero en vez de eso me lee el total de letras que hay en el TextArea ¿ Qué puedo hacer para que lea lo que le pido ?

```
private void 
jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   
    String texto="";
    texto =jTextArea1.getText().toLowerCase();
    int contador = jTextArea1.getText().length();
    contar=0;
 
    
    for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
    
     char letra = texto.charAt(i);
     
     if(letra==contar){
     contador++;
     }
    }
    jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor consulta [ask]. Si necesitas agregar aclaraciones a tu pregunta no debes hacerlo en los comentarios. **Puedes entrar a [edit]** y agregarlos de modo que sean útiles a quien piense preparar una respuesta. Te aclaro que *NetBeans* **no es un lenguaje** es un *IDE* (entorno integrado de desarrollo) **estás usando [tag:Java]** como lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errores**

```
    String texto="";
    texto =jTextArea1.getText().toLowerCase();

    // ERROR. El contador debe iniciar en 0
    int contador = jTextArea1.getText().length();

    // ERROR. Contar siempre tiene valor 0
    contar = 0;
 
    for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
    
     char letra = texto.charAt(i);
     // Esto siempre será falso por lo tanto nunca entrará
     // en la condición
     if(letra==contar){
     contador++;
     }
    }
```

**Forma correcta**

```
    String texto="";
    texto =jTextArea1.getText().toLowerCase();

    int contador = 0;
  
     // debe contener la letra a buscar
     contar = 'a';
 
    for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
    
     char letra = texto.charAt(i);

     if( letra == contar){
          contador++;
     }
    }
```

Comment: vale grasias pero me duda es como el hago si quiero leer cual quier letra y no solo una ?.?

Comment: No sé cómo está implementado el resto del programa . Si fuera un JTexField donde se ingresa la letra a buscar se puede leer al igual que se lee el valor de la variable `texto`